# Correctness of $\lim _{n\to \infty }m^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \lim _{n\to \infty }f\left(x\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \lim _{n\to \infty }M^{\frac{1}{n}}$.

Tags: calculus

> $f(x)$ is a continuous function in the interval $[a,b]$.So it has a maximum $M$ and a minimum $m$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

That is:

> $m\le f\left(x\right)\:\le M$

just like:

> $\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{'}\:=\:\frac{1}{n}x^{\frac{1}{n}-1}$.

we can't seem to detemine the monotonicity $x^{\frac{1}{n}}$ because it doesn't say that $x$ greater than $0$.

**So,is this conclusion correct?**

> $\lim _{n\to \infty }m^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \lim _{n\to \infty }f\left(x\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \lim _{n\to \infty }M^{\frac{1}{n}}$

=====update====

The initial question was:

> $f(x)$ is a continuous function in the interval $[a,b]$.And $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are on the interval $[a,b]$. What's the value of   $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum _{k=1}^{n }e^{f\left(x_k\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ ?

Comment: One issue is the existence of the limits. Second issue is with the definition of $m^{1/n}$ etc. What if $m=-1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: $\lim _{x\to \infty }m^{\frac{1}{n}}=1.$ Because  m is  constant. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Everything is fine if $m>0$.

Comment: If $m\ge0$ one can prove $m^{1/n}\le\liminf f(x)^{1/n}\le\limsup f(x)^{1/n}\le M^{1/n}$

Comment: I can't know if $m$ is greater than $0$. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: I feel Riemann's sum in that problem writing your problem as $ \frac{1}{n}\ln(e^{\ln(\frac{1}{n}\sum e^{f(x^k})})) $

Comment: I found $e^{f\left(x\right)}>0$.So $m>0$.Should I delete this question?

Comment: Is it $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum _{k=1}^{\infty }e^{f\left(x_k\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ or $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\cdot \sum _{k=1}^{n}e^{f\left(x_k\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}$ ?

Comment: k is the subscript.@EDX

Comment: I'm talking about the upper of the sum @ClancyZeng, Because a priori there is no reason for $ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{f(x_k)}$ to exist.

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typo.@EDX Now, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I ignored $e^{f\left(x\right)}>0$.So the conclusion is right.

By the way,the answer of the initial question is $1$.

Because

> $e^{f\left(x\right)}>0$,

so

> $0 < m\le e^{f\left(x\right)}\le M$

then

> $\frac{1}{n}\sum \:\:_{k=1}m\le \frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\:e^{f\left(x_k\right)}\le \frac{1}{n}\sum \:_{k=1}M$
>
> $\lim _{n\to \infty }m^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum \:_{k=1}^n\:e^{f\left(x_k\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\le \lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}M^{\frac{1}{n}}$
>
> $\lim \:_{n\to \:\infty \:}m^{\frac{1}{n}}=\:\lim \:\:_{n\to \:\:\infty \:\:}M^{\frac{1}{n}}\:=\:1$

So

> $\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum _{k=1}^n\:e^{f\left(x_k\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}=\:1$